# general OS tagging on SU

Tags: discussion, tags

On SO it's usual to find a generic tag (such as "android") together with a more specific tag (such as "android-marketplace"). This, in my opinion, is the correct way to do it.

On SU however, there are often specific tags (such as "windows-xp") without the relevant generic tag ("windows"). I found this pretty annoying.

Could this be solved, or it's somewhat intentional? (why?)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49358/addition-of-implicit-tags-closed

Answer (score 4):

It is currently intentional, though it might be worth reconsidering.  I posted [an earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45966/super-user-tagging-convention-ubuntu-and-variants) to consider the tagging convention for Ubuntu versions; that post includes a fairly current breakdown of the major OS tags that are currently in use on SU.

On Super User, I think tagging questions according to *content* provides the most useful categorization.  I think it's more useful to devote as few tags to the OS as possible, unless the question is particularly about operating systems.  This leaves the other 4 tags for whatever the question is really about.  Customizing a theme?  Image editing?  Media players?  Media format conversion?  Partitioning a hard drive?

I think most questions about solving a problem with an OS will be specific to the version of the OS.  Questions asking for software recommendations may be more general, but if you've got a problem with your network driver, it's pretty likely your question and its solutions will depend on what version of your OS you're using.

We certainly *could* stuff all Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2XYZ, and Windows XP tags into **[windows]** and **[windows-server]** tags, and likewise for Ubuntu, OSX, etc.  (**[osx]** is already the defacto OS tag for Mac OS X; the **[osx-codename]** variants are relatively scarce.)  It would be a simple process to batch-retag the various Windows and Ubuntu tags into their more general category; doing the opposite (splitting the OSX tag into the proper version-specific tags, or making sure everything tagged **[windows-7]** is also tagged **[windows]**) would be completely manual.

---

Keep in mind the tag-search wildcards (eg [**[windows~]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows~) *should* allow you to search all the OS variants at once.  This doesn't seem to work quite right when you're trying to filter by a cross-reference of tags (searching for [**[windows~]+[usb]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows~+usb) should find questions tagged **[any-windows-tag]** and **[usb]**, but doesn't)...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen both types of tagging on SO, and in my opinion, that's just fine.  There's not a reasonable way to automate the behavior you seem to want (are you sure that all instances of `subtype-tag` imply `supertype-tag`?  What about something very specific to Windows XP, that'd not present in any other version of Windows - what help does the `windows` tag provide?).  If the poster feels that a more general tag would be helpful, they should add it, but I think that's true less often than it's not.